# Logback - dynamic configuration

Tags: java, web-services, logging, logback, large-files

Is it possible to configure logback in such way that custom logback property :

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">

  <property name="logFullMessage" value="false" />

  <!-- project appenders defitions -->
  <!-- project loggers defititions -->

</configuration>
```

will influence which pattern or appender will be used ? We do have web services application which operates with large requests/responses, by default we do not wish to log request/response body, but when problem occurs we would like to have option to switch it on (logFullMessage=true) and store full response body into the log file.

Comment: Why not use LogLevel of that logger to control this? If you log full messages on `trace` level then you can switch off / switch on full messages by changing the logger's level to `trace` to switch on or to any level lower to switch off. That's what levels are for.

Comment: You could even define a special "RequestResponse" logger to control only those messages regardless from package structure. You can control the level by changing the config. Beware that if you set loglevel programmatically and set "scan = true", it will reset itself to the value in your configfile every "scanPeriod".

Comment: Changing level to TRACE could be problematic as app would start to log almost everything. Is it possible to read logback.xml configuration programatically e.g. read value of property logFullMessage and then decide whether large req/resp message will be included in log ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch the used appender you could do (only relevant lines are shown):

```
<property name="USE_APPENDER" value="FILE1" />

<appender name="FILE1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
  ....
</appender>

<appender name="FILE2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
  ....
</appender>

<root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="${USE_APPENDER}"/>
</root>
```

This in combination with the rescan options which you already have enabled makes it possible to switch the appenders.